# Finding and removing words beginning / ending with numbers

Tags: files, grep, regular-expression, search

I have a large file (>10000 lines) that contains one word per line, with a newline character after each word. The words contain no spaces.

I'd like to list (or even better, output to a new file) any words that start and/or end with a number, then I'd like to remove these from the original file. **But** I don't want to  remove words that just contain numbers.

For example, if I had the contents

```
789
hello
1hello
112121hello3323
he11o
hello9
88888
```

Then the strings `1hello`, `112121hello3323`, `hello9` would get output and then removed from the file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU grep

```
grep -vP '^\d+\D|\D\d+$'
```

produces

```
789
hello
he11o
88888
```

Comment: or POSIXly, `grep -vE '^[[:digit:]]+[^[:digit:]]|[^[:digit:]][[:digit:]]+$'`

Comment: @1_CR Yeah i was going to add that but wasn't 100% that -E was completely posix compliant.

Answer (score 1):

To actually edit the source file and create a new file with the discards is a bit trickier. I would do this

```
$ cat file
789
hello
1hello
112121hello3323
he11o
hello9
88888

$ perl -i -lne 'if (/^\d+\D|\D\d+$/) {warn "$_\n"} else {print}' file 2>file_nums

$ cat file
789
hello
he11o
88888

$ cat file_nums
1hello
112121hello3323
hello9
```

The matched lines are output on stderr, which is then redirected to a separate file. perl's `-i` flag takes care of saving the changes in-place.

The one-liner can be even trickier:

```
perl -i -lne 'print {/^\d+\D|\D\d+$/ ? STDERR : ARGVOUT} $_' file 2>file_nums
```

Comment: Note that this will also write any warnings or errors from perl into file_nums.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '$0!~/.*[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+$/ && $0!~/^[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+/' words.txt
789
hello
he11o
88888
```